# Exception occured when connecting java to oracle 10g

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

My code is as below.

```
java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
java.sql.Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "ims", "_ims");
```

The exception occurs at second line which is given below.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:xe"
```

What does exception means? Whats wrong in my code?

**Edit by Girish**

the listener.ora file :

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Girish-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

The tnsnames.ora file :

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Girish-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

In above, both tnsnames.ora and listener.ora file's contents is given.

Comment: is `listener.ora` file available under `oracle\admin\network`. If available check the `port` and `service`.

Comment: yes, both files available, and also entries in that file are available.

Comment: @Girish  try your system IP in place of `localhost`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've replaced my oracle**.jar with new one, n its work. I think there was problem with my old oracle**.jar. Thanks to everyone for support.

Answer (score 1):

It means given sid(xe) is not available.

Listener is not able to recognise or find it in listener.ora or tnsnames.ora file.Please check the files and verify whether  entry for the xe sid is present or not.

If entry is present in the above files then check listener is running or not.

** Updated**

Use below jdbc url

jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:1521/XE

Comment: both (as you said) .ora files are available, also oracle's services are running.

Comment: entries for the xe sid are present in those files?, can u please post the contents here...

Comment: Entries available in both files.

Comment: Exception : `java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83509/discussion-between-anjali-and-girish).

Comment: try this ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661610/tns-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript

Comment: this one also...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192521/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript

Answer (score 1):

your are using sting like

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:1521:XE
```

try like

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:1521/XE
```

Because I'm already faced same issue. with this I resolved it.

Make sure that `OracleServiceXE`, `OracleXETNSListener` is running.

[Still facing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805705/java-oracle-localhost-connection-error-ora-12505)

Comment: I've did as per your suggestion, but the following exception occured : `java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`

Comment: so check username and password whether you enter correct or not. Also may network setup. Make sure that `OracleServiceXE`, `OracleXETNSListener` is running.

Comment: Also OracleServiceXE and OracleXETNSListener is running.

Comment: I've tested as per your updated answer and comment. But not working. Now I'm asking silly question, is there any problem with oracle 10g setup I have?

Comment: who exactly knows that. since it was install in your system.